# Subprojection of a finite projection

Tags: operator-algebras

The question is entirely explained here, in that I wonder why every source seems to regard as obvious the claim that subprojections of finite projections are finite.

Here is the [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=1nSIDKJjFl0C&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=subprojection%20of%20finite%20projection%20is%20finite&source=bl&ots=Pxewy73qSS&sig=aNEFrxjYqQTXSygZC9mwW9EwYw8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FOzTT67aN7Gy0AG514iMAw&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=subprojection%20of%20finite%20projection%20is%20finite&f=false).

To me, playing around with the tools and relations at hand doesn't work, and that's what would have to work before I'd make something a remark without further proof.  So, I mean, I let $f$ be a subprojection of $e$ when $e$ is finite, and then if $g$ is a strict subprojection of $f$ then I need to show $g$ is not equivalent to $f$, so I notice $g$ is also a strict subprojection of $e$, hence is not equivalent to it, and then everything comes to a grinding halt.  I must be missing something *really* easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. Suppose that $f\in M$ is a finite projection, i.e., if $e \in M$ is a projection with $e \leq f$, $e \sim f$, then $e=f$.

Let $g \in M$ be a projection such that $g \leq f$. We will show that $g$ is finite. So we consider a projection $h \in M$, such that $h\leq g$ with $h\sim g$, and we seek to show that $h=g$. The basic idea is to move from a statement about $g$ to a statement about $f$ and so we are led to consider the difference $f-g$.

As $g \leq f$, we have that $(f-g)$ is a projection. Note that $(f-g)+h \leq f$. Then we have, as $(f-g)\perp h$ and $(f-g)\perp g$ (*), that
$$
(f-g) + h \sim (f-g)+g=f.
$$
By finiteness of $f$, we have that $(f-g)+h=f$. Thus $g=h$ and $g$ is finite.

Further details on (*): If $vv^*=e \sim e_1=v^*v$, and  $uu^*=f \sim f_1=u^*u$, with $e \perp f$, $e_1 \perp f_1$, then $$(u+v)^*(u+v)=e+f \sim e_1+f_1 =(u+v)(u+v)^*.$$ Just keep in mind what the supports of the partial isometries $u$ and $v$ are.