# Every abelian projection in a von Neumann algebra is finite

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I saw a note on von Neumann algebras, it mentions that every abelian projection $p$ in a von Neumann algebra is finite.

According to the definitions, we know that $pMp$ is abelian, we need to prove that for any projection $q\in M$ such that $q\leq p$ and $q\sim p$, we have $p=q$.

It is easy to see that $pq=qp=q$, how do I use the condition $p\sim q$ to conclude that $p=q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p=u^*u$ and $q=uu^*$, then
$$u=uu^*u=qu=pqu=pu=pup\in pMp.$$
Since $p$ is abelian, it now follows that
$$p=u^*u=uu^*=q.$$

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the properties of a partial isometry.

Comment: Why is $pqu = pu$?